# .asax.cs page is appending :443 to URLs

Tags: c#, ssl, https

I am not familiar with ASP or C# but I am in a conundrum where after forcing SSL /Mobile view URLS are appended with :443. For example users will be served https://www.example.com/Mobile:443/
Instead of :
https://www.example.com/Mobile

This is what I believe is the relevant secion of code in global.asax.cs page:

```
            if (!isOnMobilePage && !isOnMobilePageJSLib && !isOnMobilePageImages && !isOnMobilePageContent && !isOnMobilePageScripts && !isOnMobilePageJS && !isOnMobilePagescrollbar && !isOnMobilePagefonts)
            {
                string URL1 = Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                Uri uri1 = new Uri(URL1);
                UriBuilder builder1 = new UriBuilder(uri1);
                builder1.Host = builder1.Host + "/Mobile";

                Uri result1 = builder1.Uri;
                URL1 = result1.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                string redirectTo1 = URL1.Replace(":80", "");

               HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo1);
            }
```

You are all s

Answer (score 0):

443 is the SSL port.   To remove it, try

```
  builder1.Port = -1;
```

before you append /Mobile